# <ng-select> [items] value don't update

Tags: angular, list, typescript

I am working on a page where I need a select box with search field, so I decided to use the `ngSelect` module for it.

My HTML:

```
   <ng-select [items]="mesurePoints"
            bindLabel="name"
            bindValue="id"
            >
   </ng-select>
```

select list is not linked to `mesurePoints` value after some changes.

Comment: Try binding a model to it  <ng-select [items]="mesurePoints"
            bindLabel="name"
            bindValue="id" [(ngModel)]="yourModel"
            >
   </ng-select>

Comment: You mean after changing the `mesurePoints` array value ?

Comment: I create a small stackblitz here, can't reproduce. Can you please a fork to reproduce the bug. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49798743

Comment: With some tests on stackblitz, I understood my mistake.  Changes on my list happened in a call of service function.  So I just had this in this function

app.component.ts:
mesurePoints = Object.assign(value);

Answer (score 15):

```
this.mesurePoints = [...this.mesurePoints]
```

It will update your Items https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#change-detection

Answer (score -8):

You can simply use html `select` tag

please take a look to the code below

```
<select [(ngModel)]="myvar">
<option *ngFor="let var of listOfVars"  [value]="var">{{var}}</option>
</select>
```

where :

**myvar** is the variable that will contain the selected value (it should be declared on typescript component).

**listOfVars** is the list that conatins you variable list in your case it's **mesurePoints**.